# Function lookup on Hoogle CLI doesn't show function descriptions

Tags: haskell, command-line, documentation, hoogle

When I search for `nub` on haskell.org/hoogle, it returns a list of matching functions along with helpful descriptions, such as "The nub function removes duplicate elements from a list". Is there any way to get this functionality from the Hoogle CLI?

Comment: @NeilMitchell  (does this work?)

Comment: @luqui Unfortunately not...

Comment: I have moved [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48969298/2751851) to the question I closed yours against.